# Laravel - Multisheet Excel

Tags: php, laravel-8

I tried to export my data in multi sheet Excel. But I face the error like

Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError
Class App\Exports\ReportExport contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromQuery::query)

Maatwebsite\Excel\Sheet::formatColumn(): Argument #2 ($format) must be of type string, array given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\healthcare\vendor\maatwebsite\excel\src\Sheet.php on line 395

My controller coding is

```
public function exportproviders($id)
    {
        
        $providerid = $id;  
    
        return Excel::download(new ReportExport($providerid), 'users.xlsx');
    }
```

ReportExport

```
class ReportExport implements WithMultipleSheets
{
  
    use Exportable;
    public function __construct(int $providerid)
    {
        $this->providerid = $providerid;
        
    }
    public function sheets(): array
    {
        $sheets = [
            new ReportGeneralExport($this->providerid),
            new ReportPracticeExport($this->providerid),
            new ReportEducationExport($this->providerid),
            new ReportWorkingExport($this->providerid),
            new ReportCertificateExport($this->providerid),
            new ReportReferenceExport($this->providerid),
            new ReportQuestionsExport($this->providerid),
            new ReportDocumentsExport($this->providerid),
        ];

        return $sheets;
    }
}
```

ReportGeneralExport

```
use App\Models\Providerinfo;

class ReportGeneralExport implements FromQuery, WithHeadings, WithTitle, ShouldAutoSize, WithColumnFormatting, WithMapping
{
    use Exportable;

    public function __construct(int $providerid)
    {
        $this->providerid = $providerid;
    }

    public function map($row): array
    {
        return [
            $row['providername'],
            $row['middlename'],
            $row['lastname'],
            $row['email'],
            $row['official_email'],
            $row['home_address'],
            $row['home_city'],
            $row['home_state'],
            $row['home_country'],
            $row['home_zipcode'],
            $row['mail_address'],
        ];
    }
    public function query()
    {
        return Providerinfo::where('id',$this->providerid)->get();
    }

    public function headings(): array
    {
        return [
            'First Name',
            'Middle Name',
            'Last Name',
            'Email Id',
            'Other Email Id',
            'Home Address',
            'Home City',
            'Home State',
            'Home Country',
            'Home Zipcode',
            'Mail Address',
        ];
    }
}
```

Using Providerid to get the data from the `providerinfo` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ReportGeneralExport` class contains a lot of implements there.

I see [WithTitle](https://github.com/SpartnerNL/Laravel-Excel/blob/3.1/src/Concerns/WithTitle.php) but no implementation of:

```
public function title(): string;
```

Either implement it or remove `WithTitle` from your implements.

I also see [WithColumnFormatting](https://github.com/SpartnerNL/Laravel-Excel/blob/3.1/src/Concerns/WithColumnFormatting.php) but no implementation of:

```
public function columnFormats(): array;
```

Either implement it or remove `WithColumnFormatting` from your implements.

Also remove the `->get()` from your query:

```
    public function query()
    {
        return Providerinfo::where('id',$this->providerid)->get();
    }
```

As per the [documentation](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/from-query.html) it says:

> Be sure to **not** `->get()` the results!

Comment: I removed. But it shows error like Class App\Exports\ReportReferenceExport contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromQuery::query)

Comment: @MukhilaAsokan I see `query` implemented inside of your `ReportGeneralExport` class. That's an odd error to see if it's implemented correctly. Might make sure you're editing the right file and your changes are applying correctly. Might also try removing `FromQuery` from the implements and see if that fixes it, even though you implemented it correctly.

Comment: thanks Excel Sheet downloaded, But it return empty

Comment: @MukhilaAsokan Try adding the `FromQuery` back.  As per the documentation https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/from-query.html it says `Be sure to not ->get() the results!` You are calling `->get()` on the results. Instead use `return Providerinfo::where('id',$this->providerid);`